# Hardware Tool to test Memory modules

Tags: memory

I have ton's of memory modules (mostly old ones) but also DDR3's DDR2's SODIMMS and more.

Is there any tool/appliance that I can connect the memory to it (preferrably USB), and it will test it?

I don't want to have to sit around an open PC, and plug/unplug DIMMS.

Comment: Not as far as i know. Such a device would be *shiny* as hell tho

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There seem to be [standalone devices](https://www.google.com/search?q=usb%20tester&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a&channel=fflb#q=memory%20tester&hl=en&client=firefox-a&hs=foZ&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&channel=fflb&prmd=imvnsa&source=univ&tbm=shop&tbo=u&sa=X&ei=wQHOT86vBM_irAe21eSjDA&sqi=2&ved=0CI0BEK0E&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.,cf.osb&fp=e85b24616effa262&biw=1600&bih=839) that do this (sorry for the google link, but i'm confirming there's such things NOT making a specific recommendation) , but looking at the prices, unless you needed a LOT of ram tested, getting an appropriate system and an open case seems like a better idea.

They also seem to be specific to memory types, though there seem to be adaptors to convert between desktop and laptop varients.

Answer (score 3):

**Hardware** devices that tests memory exist, such as [RAMCHECK](http://www.innoventions.com/) and products from [CST Inc](http://www.simmtester.com/). But they are expensive, and aimed at companies which manufacture memory modules.